# Measure (largest) eigenvalue at a fixed point from (high-dimensional) time series data

Tags: time-series, nonlinear, eigenvalues

I have a time series of a high dimensional dynamical system, of the form 
$$
\{\vec{Y}(t_1), \vec{Y}(t_2),\dots, \vec{Y}(t_n)\}, 
$$
where $\vec{Y}(t_i) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $m$ is quite large, and $\vec{Y}(t) = \vec{X}(t)$, where $\vec{X}(t)$ governed by an underlying noisy dynamical system 
$$
\frac{d\vec{X}}{dt}  =\vec{F}(\vec{X}) + \eta d \vec{W}.
$$

Through other means I can establish that for all $i=1, \dots, N$ my system is close to a fixed point (either stable or unstable), and I would like to figure out if this fixed point is stable or unstable. This, of course, can be figured out by calculating the largest eigenvalue at this fixed point. My question:

**Using only (noisy) time series data drawn from a potentially high dimensional dynamical system which can be assumed to be in the neighborhood of a single fixed point, how can I calculate the largest eigenvalue of the dyanmical system at that fixed point?**